# zshrc doesn't recognize custom bash functions

Tags: bash, git, zsh

I recently moved from bash to zsh, and like most of people I had my custom bash aliases/functions to ease git and env sourcing operations. In particular there are 2 of them which doesn't work properly when run on zsh but work completely fine on bash.

```
export REPO_ROOT=/home/pablo/repos/my_repo
alias croot='cd $REPO_ROOT'
alias subroot='cd $REPO_ROOT/subrepo/subrepo_1/'

repcheckout(){
 git checkout "$1"
 if [ $(pwd) == $REPO_ROOT ];  then
   subroot
 else
   croot
 fi
 git checkout "$1"
 if [ $(pwd) == $REPO_ROOT ];  then
   subroot
 else
   croot
 fi
}
```

The idea is that I have a set of main_repo-submodule branches and when I checkout the main repo, I want to checkout the submodule in the corresponding branch, instead of doing:

```
$ git submodule update --init --recursive subrepo/subrepo_1
```

which checkouts the proper commit in the submodule but doesn't update that I switched to a certain local branch.

For the previous func, the error dropped by zsh when running

```
$ repcheckout my_cool_branch
```

is

```
M       subrepo/subrepo_1/
Switched to branch 'my_cool_branch'
repcheckout:2: = not found
```

Later I have a setup.sh file that I source which goes as follows:

```
add2path() {
    if ! echo ${!1} | egrep "(^|:)$2(:|\$)" > /dev/null ; then
    declare -g $1="${!1}:$2"
    export "$1"
    fi
}

# GENERATED BINARY A
export BIN_A_HOME="$REPO_ROOT/bin_a"
add2path PATH "$BIN_A_HOME/bin"
```

Same with some generated python modules that are added to PYTHONPATH using the same add2path

Which drops the error:

```
add2path:1: bad substitution
```

Comment: You could rewrite the condition as `[[ $PWD == $REPO_ROOT ]]`. No need to create a child process just for checking the working directory. Using `[[ ... ]]` also allows you to use the `==` operator. BTW, `${!1}` also does not work in zsh. In general, it does not make sense to blindly run code written for one language under another language, even if the languages have similarities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both functions use bashisms that aren't valid in zsh.

In `repcheckout`, the problem is using the `==` operator in a `[ ]` test -- the standard operator is `=`, but bash allows `==` as a synonym; zsh doesn't. I'd also recommend double-quoting both strings to avoid problems with weird characters in the path (and maybe using `"$PWD"` instead of `$(pwd)`):

```
if [ "$PWD" = "$REPO_ROOT" ];  then
```

In `add2path`, the problem is the indirect variable reference `${!1}` in both the `echo` and `declare` commands. zsh also allows indirect variable  references, but its syntax is completely different: `${(P)1}`. You could probably make a cross-compatible version with `eval`, but that tends to cause weird bugs if you don't use it exactly right; I'd just rewrite the function as needed for zsh.

EDIT: If you want to use the same code under both bash and zsh, `eval` is probably better than trying to detect which shell you're in and using conditional code based on that. Here's a quick stab at writing a cross-shell compatible version:

```
if ! eval "echo \"\$$1\"" | egrep "(^|:)$2(:|\$)" > /dev/null ; then
    eval "declare -g $1=\"\$$1:\$2\""
    export "$1"
    ...
```

The quoting is ugly, but it should work ok as long as `$1` contains a valid identifier; if it doesn't, the usual `eval` problems may rear their ugly heads.

Comment: My impression is that the quoting fix isn't necessary for Zsh, but it certainly improves the Bash code.

Comment: And what about detecting in the script from where is it called, either from bash or zsh to use one version of the function or another ? Or that's not possible

Comment: repcheckout works like a charm now, thanks. I will see what can I do with add2path

Comment: @tripleee Like seemingly everything in `zsh`, whether or not parameter expansions are subject to word-splitting is configurable. While the *default* is to not perform word-splitting, I wouldn't write code that relies on a particular setting. (Plus, `[[ ... ]]` is available to make it a moot point.)

Comment: @picatostas I added a method of using `eval` that should work on both bash and zsh.